# Execute Datetime from C# to date in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

I'm new in programming and want you to help me.
I have field of type (date) and when I insert data to database from my website in visual studio 2010 with C#, it Shows me an error during execution.
Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Code behind

```
string InsMus = "Insert into StoreMus (MusNo,MusDate)" +
                 "Values (" + Convert.ToInt16(txtMusNo.Text) + ",'" + DateTime.Parse(txtMusDate.Text) + "')";
cmd = new SqlCommand(InsMus , con);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? What are the types of your columns? Why do you want to keep your `DateTime` as a character? And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Use *parameters* instead of SQL hardcoding: parameterized SQL is faster and not prone to SQL injection

Comment: Despite the obvious answer (use parameters) your code converts strings to int/datetime then back to string. The only way this won't result in the same text as the original, is when an unexpected conversion occurs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: but apart from the fact that he should use parameters anyway, there's a difference: if the format is invalid `DateTime.Parse` throws an exception which is better than passing everything to the DB.

Comment: Which value comes from txtMusDate?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I wanted to point out the unnecessary back and forth conversion. Checking the value is part of validation, which hopefully, has already been performed before sending the value to the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: since OP is a beginner i'm pleasantly surprised that he's using `DateTime.Parse` at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use string concanation to prevent sql injection. I'm sure that it will also fix this issue.

```
string InsMus = @"Insert into StoreMus (MusNo,MusDate)
                   Values (@MusNo, @MusDate);";
using(var con = new SqlConnection("Connection String..."))
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(InsMus, con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MusNo", SqlDbType.SmallInt).Value = short.Parse(txtMusNo.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@MusDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Parse(txtMusDate.Text);
    con.Open();
    int inserted = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Note that i've used the `using`-statement to ensure that the connection gets disposed/closed.

You could also use `DateTime.TryParse` instead of `DateTime.Parse` to prevent an exception that happens when the format of the date is invalid:

```
DateTime musDate;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(txtMusDate.Text, out musDate))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid mus-date.");
    return;
}
// here you can use musDate
```